# How does a windows phone sockets game work ? Bluetooth? XBOX LIVE api ?

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, windows-phone-7.1

Must a game be client server which then requires me to stand up a server? If so, can I do that on a web host? Azure?  ..

If not, then how do the 2 window phone clients find each other?

I am having difficulty understand the main blocks invovled in doing this and how they come together...

What about bluetooth ? From what I have read so far there is no access to the bluetooth api ?

Is there or wil lthere be any helpers from xbox live and thier api to let a indie dev set up connections ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for creating a real time multiplayer game.

1. Devices connect over the internet or used a web based mediator to relay game data.
2. Devices connet via sockets over UDP.

If you choose option 1 then you can host your web based component anywhere.

If you choose 2 then there is a sample that may be of interest at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

There is, currently, no support for working with BlueTooth in the API.